# Vs2017 how to build target Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-c++, windows-7, visual-studio-2017, windows-7-embedded

i have one project that runs on windows 7 machines
Well windows 7 embeded, but that still uses win7 SDK.
Its a combination of windows C# and C++

Under vs2017 i no longer have the option to build to the windows 7 target platform (C++ and c#), the lowest i have is windows 8.1

Trying to install 7 sdk results in all kind of chickken egg problems
Took me 2 days install vs2017 with a working c++ crt, so i hope there is a way to re-add win 7 sdk for vs2017.

Or maybe I wonder is there an option to build 8.1 but not use too advanced futures, as 8.1 and 7 besides the glitter graphics was not such a huge change (ea most win 7 apps run fine on 8.1, and i never saw serious programs who worked only on 8.1) Maybe even 8.1 SDK has some backward compatibility build in?